# How to find out if the output is cached?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have the following MVC-Controller Action:

```
[Route("{id}")]
[UserAuth(Roles =Directory.GroupUser)]
[OutputCache(Duration = 600)]
public ActionResult Select()
{
DoSelect();
}
```

The UserAuth-Attribute gets Values from the Session. When the content is cached (by Outputcache) however, the Session is null. This would be ok, cause I do not have to revalidate when the data is already in the cache.

But how can I find out if the output is cached (and just disable the authentication then)? Is there a property for that?